# Pass parameters automatically to oracle plsql function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I have wrote two `plsql functions` for Stock and Sales Comparison. one as `find_prodcuts_sold` and other as `find_usage_from_stock`.

I can get different between stock and sales by decrease `find_prodcuts_sold` function from `find_usage_from_stock` function. for this i should pass `From date` and `To date` to these two functions. (`From date` and `To date` are taken from `stock_date` column in `stock` table). then my functions return values for given date range.

Now i want to create a `line chart` using my functions to get different between stock and slaes. chart should build automatically. with out user pass `From date` and `To date`.

Example `stock_date` column from `stock table`.

```
stock_date

30-JAN-12
26-JAN-12
24-JAN-12
23-JAN-12
18-JAN-12
15-JAN-12
13-JAN-12
12-JAN-12
11-JAN-12
08-JAN-12
06-JAN-12
```

I want to pass above dates as below to my functions automatically.

```
From        To
26-JAN-12   30-JAN-12
24-JAN-12   26-JAN-12
23-JAN-12   24-JAN-12
18-JAN-12   23-JAN-12
15-JAN-12   18-JAN-12
13-JAN-12   15-JAN-12
12-JAN-12   13-JAN-12
11-JAN-12   12-JAN-12
08-JAN-12   11-JAN-12
06-JAN-12   08-JAN-12
```

how could i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LAG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) or [LEAD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm) analytic functions:

```
select stock_date, lead(stock_date, 1, null) over (order by stock_date) next_date
from stock_table
```

then use the result of the query for your input, i.e.:

```
SELECT find_usage_from_stock(t.product_id, t.start_date, t.end_date) as usage_from_stock, 
       find_prodcuts_sold(t.product_id, t.start_date, t.end_date) as prodcuts_sold, 
       t.product_id, t.start_date
FROM (select stock_date as start_date, 
             lead(stock_date, 1, null) over (order by stock_date) as end_date, 
             product_id
      from stock_table) t
```

Note: I used null as the empty value in the lead function, perhaps you'll need to put something else

Comment: A.B.Cade, your answer is correct. but i have no idea about how to pass dates return from your answer as parameters to my functions. how can i do that ?

there are two functions as below.

`find_usage_from_stock(p_id,from_date,to_date);`
`find_prodcuts_sold(p_id,from_date,to_date);`

Comment: how are you running these function ? using a script (plsql) ? creating a DB view ? basiccaly you can use them in a select statement, ie- select find_usage_from_stock(p_id,t.stock_date,t.next_date) from (select stock_date, lead(stock_date, 1, null) over (order by stock_date) next_date
from stock_table) t

Comment: A.B.Cade, i use my functions to create chart in oracle apex.

Comment: @Bishan, I'm not familiar with oracle apex, but from what i've seen in some tutorials, you can build a chart from a sql query. If I'm right then the example in my prev comment can be a start (I didn't know what to put in p_id)

Comment: A.B.Cade, Thanks for your prev example. My question is not solve yet. but your prev example gave me a start to my work. sorry for the p_id :) it is product_id

Comment: @Bishan, I added the example to the answer, perhaps now it'll be more clearer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7189/discussion-between-bishan-and-a-b-cade)

Comment: A.B.Cade,
 [let us continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7189/discussion-between-bishan-and-a-b-cade)